# facing issue in terraform, while running it for IAM policy attachment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So I am trying to assign multiple policies to users which i have defined in policies.tf file and when running it is showing an error. I am using gitlab to run this, also i am able to solve this error if i am defining s3_policy directly like aws_iam_policy.s3_policy.arn

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3_policy" {
  name        = "s3-policy"
  description = "S3 IAM policy"
    
  # Define the policy document with the required permissions
  policy = <<-JSON
    {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
         {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": "s3:GetObject",
           "Resource": "*"
         }
       ]
    }
    JSON
}
    
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_policy" {
  name        = "ec2-policy"
  description = "EC@ IAM policy"
    
  # Define the policy document with the required permissions
  policy = <<-JSON
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "ec2:*",
          "Resource": "*"
        }
      ]
    }
    JSON
}

# Your aws_iam_user_policy_attachment resource definition
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "user_policies" {
  for_each = toset(var.user_policies)
    
  user   = module.iam_user_module.aws_iam_user.this[0].name
    
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy[each.value].arn
}
```

The error i am getting is

> Error: Invalid reference
> │
> │   on modules/iam_module/policies.tf line 43, in resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "user_policies":
> │   43:   policy_arn = aws_iam_policy[each.value].arn
> │
> │ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
> │ access, specifying the resource name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policy resource was created without using `for_each` meta-argument, so you need to use the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3_policy" {
  name        = "s3-policy"
  description = "S3 IAM policy"

  # Define the policy document with the required permissions
  policy = <<-JSON
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
  JSON
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_policy" {
  name        = "ec2-policy"
  description = "EC2 IAM policy"

  # Define the policy document with the required permissions
  policy = <<-JSON
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:*",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
  JSON
}


# Your aws_iam_user_policy_attachment resource definition
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "ec2_policy" {
  user       = module.iam_user_module.aws_iam_user.this[0].name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ec2_policy.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "s3_policy" {
  user       = module.iam_user_module.aws_iam_user.this[0].name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_policy.arn
}
```

Note that when using [implicit references](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/references#references-to-resource-attributes), the syntax is:

```
<resource type>.<logical name>.<attribute>
```

or in your case

```
| aws_iam_policy  | ec2_policy    | arn
| resource type   | logical name  | attribute
```

Since the policy is assigned to the same user, alternatively what can be done is the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policies" {
  name        = "ec2-s3-policy"
  description = "EC2 and S3 IAM policy"

  # Define the policy document with the required permissions
  policy = <<-JSON
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:*",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
  JSON
}


# Your aws_iam_user_policy_attachment resource definition
resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "user_policy" {
  user       = module.iam_user_module.aws_iam_user.this[0].name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.iam_policy.arn
}
```

Comment: yeah what you mentioned policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ec2_policy.arn works but i need to add multiple policies like 2 policies that i have defined, how do i then attach both policies  to user

Comment: In that case, you would need to add another resource of the same type and reference the second policy.

Comment: can't i use a single resource and use it dynamically?

Comment: can you help me out in this i dont want to declare so many policies resources

Comment: Both policies need to be attached to the same user?

Comment: I am trying to make a list of policies which will be declared beforehand and i will attach them by giving its value in variable name in main file

Comment: Sorry, but that's a completely different question to the original one. I've updated the answer so it explains how to add the both policies in one step.